# New post dynamically shown in dropdown menu in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a Wordpress site with DIVI theme.

Suppose I have two categories `complete project` and `ongoing project`. These two categories are already in Menubarbar with dropdown list.

[image: completed project]
[image: ongoing project]

I manually create this dropdown menu from `Appearance->Menus`.

Now I want that, while I add a new post under `ongoing project`/ `completed project` category, the dropdown list of Menubar will automatically updated dynamically with the new post.

Please Help.Thanks in Advance.